# IP Camera with PTZ through stunnel

Tags: configuration, stunnel

Looking around at first it was suggest to use a reverse proxy to wrap https around and IP camera and then someone mentioned you don't get sound that way so they said use stunnel. I'm looking at stunnel and I'm not sure how to connect to the camera and the let it out into the wild with two ports, one is for the RTP and the other is for the PTZ. My best guess is below assuming the IP Camera is on the fixed IP address of 192.168.11.22:

```
[cam1-rtsp]
connect = 192.168.11.22:80
accept = 554

[cam1-ptz]
connect = 192.168.11.22:80
accept = 5678
```

Can anyone tell me if this is the right (or at least a reasonable) way to do this or if it's just completely wrong in which case some help in a workable configuration for stunnel would be appreciated.

Part of what bothers me with this is that this is an `onvif` camera which means it will come in on 80 and gather information about the camera and then connect with 554 & 5678 but whereas I imagine that 554 is purely going out by the camera I suspect that 5678 coming in by the phone app so perhaps:

```
[cam1-ptz]
connect = 192.168.11.22:80
accept = 5678
```

should be:

```
[cam1-ptz]
connect = 192.168.11.22:5678
accept = 5678
```

or some such thing. If someone with experience with stunnel could chime in and especially if you have experience with PTZ cameras as well that would be awesome.

BTW, I'm basing the configuration from this post http://warped.org/blog/2013/08/08/foscam_ipcam_https/ as this person seems to have gotten it working but s/he doesn't handle PTZ.

Thanks!